# Direction of static friction in an inclined plane

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, free-body-diagram

[image]

Let us suppose an object is placed on an inclined plane. Let us also assume the surface has a coefficient of *static friction* $\mu$. The object is being pulled by a force $F$. As a result, the object is in equilibrium. My question is what is the direction of the frictional force?

Here are my two *most probably inappropriate* logics in favour of two directions:

1)The direction is upward because $mg\sin \alpha$ is trying to bring the object downward. And as we know, static friction will try to prevent the object from going downward. Hence, it will act in the upward direction.

2)The direction is downward. By applying $F$ force, we are taking the object in the upward direction. And friction resists the motion of the object. So the direction of static friction is downward.

I am really confused since both $F$ and $mg\sin \alpha$ forces are making the object move in two different directions, so I can't really understand in which direction friction should be. Please clear my misconception.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, both your suggestions can be correct depending on the magnitude of F. In equilibrium $F=mg\sin\alpha$ + static friction. Now if $F>mg\sin\alpha$ then the object should move up the ramp, so to balance it static friction acts down the ramp. If $F<mg\sin\alpha$ then the object should move down the ramp so to balance it static friction must act up the ramp. And if $F=mg\sin\alpha$ there is no need for static friction. So the direction of static friction depends on whether $F$ or $mg\sin\alpha$ is larger.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is what is the direction of the frictional force?

First of all, there will only be a friction force if $F\ne mg\sin\alpha$ because friction only exists in opposition to a net applied force on the block.

If $F\lt mg\sin\alpha$ there will be a friction force acting up the plane opposing the net force acting down the plane of $mg\sin\theta-F$. If the friction force does not exceed the maximum possible static friction force of $\mu mg\cos\theta$, then the static friction force will equal $mg\sin\theta-F$ acting up the plane and the block will be in equilibrium. *Keep in mind that the static friction force always matches the net force applied to the block up until the maximum possible static friction force is reached.*

If $F\gt mg\sin\alpha$ there will be a friction force acting down the plane opposing the net force of $F-mg\sin\theta$ acting up the plane. Again, if the friction force does not exceed the maximum possible static friction force of $\mu mg\cos\theta$, then the static friction force acting down the plane will equal $F-mg\sin\theta$ and the block will be in equilibrium.

If the maximum possible static friction force is exceeded, then in the first case the block will slide down the plane and in the second case the block will slide up the plane and the friction force changes from static to kinetic (sliding) friction. In each case a kinetic friction force of $\mu_{k}mg\cos\theta$ will oppose the motion where $\mu_k$ is the coefficient of kinetic friction (which is generally less than the coefficient of static friction). The difference between the two forces divided by the mass will equal the acceleration of the mass.

Hope this helps.